# How do I use headlessjs react native expo?

Tags: react-native

I'm coding in react native and I want to make my app run in the background on android phones only. I want to allow my phone to open a webbrowser in the background in react native without the app being open. How can I do this?

My code so far is:

```
// Note the additional import of useEffect
import React, { useState, useEffect,  useRef  } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    _handlePressButtonAsync();
  }, []);

  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);


  
  const _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://vitech-104517.square.site/');
    setResult(result);
    
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Open WebBrowser" onPress={_handlePressButtonAsync} />
      <Text>{result && JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

I'm not sure how to import headlessjs or run headlessjs in my project. My project is using expo. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using BackgroundFetch from Expo. This api allows you to run tasks in background periodically.
Link to the Docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `expo-task-manager` which provides you with an API that allows you to manage long-running tasks, in particular, tasks that run while your app is running in the background. [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/#background-modes-on-ios)